# decreasing the size of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi
I have a question that in the bellow code do we need to write `n--;` ?

```
        int n = pointList.size();
    for(int i=pointList.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
            if(pointList.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
                pointList.remove(i);
                n--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also list is an arrayList.
thanks.

Comment: dude, you need to write more information about what you want.

Comment: you should stop the loop over `j` after you have removed the `ith` element, because you will be accessing the `ith` element of `pointList` in the next iteration of the inner (`j`) loop...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayList` is backed by an array that starts at a fixed size and is only resized if it needs a larger size.  As far as I'm aware, you can only shrink the size of `ArrayList`'s backing store using [`trimToSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)

If the size of the store is important, consider using a `LinkedList` instead.

Note:

If I'm reading your code correctly, you can replace all the code you posted with just this instead:

```
pointList.removeAll(list);
```

Comment: You're not reading it correctly. list and pointList are different things.

Comment: @Paul: How so?  From the variable names, both are lists, and from the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) of `Collection`'s `remove` method, it uses this logic for comparing them: `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean by "different things". The Elements in the list are all from the same type. And he wants to remove every element from pointList which is in list...

Comment: Foo. It's me not reading correctly. Sorry for the misdirection

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, since `n` is never read anywhere.

I believe, this is a relict from earlier, where the developer added this either to use n in a debug.print statement, or in an assertion.

Comment: I think there's an implied use of n further on. But since pointlist.size will return the adjusted size (unless bizarrely implemented, "remove" will adjust the size) there's no need to track it via the use of n.

Comment: Where did the -1 come from? And why?

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't really a question here I will take a guess.  My guess is that the declaration of `int n = pointList.size();` is redundant.  Since you will always have `pointList` it will know its size.  Also I am willing to bet that is going to throw a concurrent modification exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because the ArrayList will decrease it's size each time you remove an item you don't have to use n at all.

if you do the following after each iteration, it will achieve the same result:

pointList.remove(pointList.size() - 1);

The -1 is there because obviously arrays start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess that you want to keep the size of the pointList stored in n up to date. In this case you have to decrease n. But you can simply assign n after the double for loop.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this? It is completely correct. I just upvoted to bring it back to zero.